# Is it possible to use ContentChild and query for any arbitrary component?

Tags: angular

I'm building a wrapper for form fields to make their presentation consistent throughout the app. I would like to be able to get a reference to the component or directive that has a `formControl` attached (or more specifically, i want to get a reference to the `FormControl` itself.

Here's an example usage in a template:

```js
<field-wrapper>
  <input pInputText [formControl]='username'>
  <!-- other stuff -->
</field-wrapper>
```

Here, I want `FieldWrapperComponent` to be able to get a handle on the `formControl` of the input field or any other arbitrary child component.

Specifically, I'm using primeng which comes with a lot of different form elements. So far I've been trying with `ContentChild`, but there is no common way to query for all of them that i've been able to identify.

Is there some other way to accomplish this?

Answer (score -1):

You can use `@ViewChildren` in `FieldWrapperComponent` like below:

```js
import { FormControlDirective } from "@angular/forms";

...
export class FieldWrapperComponent {

 @ViewChildren(FormControlDirective) formControlDirectiveList: QueryList<FormControlDirective>; 

}
```